# How to change code to add one check box to ActiveCell instead of ActiveSheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code written that has an if statement to add check boxes to certain cells in ActiveSheet if certain conditions are met. My code below shows that code.

```
'To add checkboxes
Dim ToRow As Long
Dim LastRowCB As Long
Dim MyLeft As Double
Dim MyTop As Double
Dim MyHeight As Double
Dim MyWidth As Double

LastRowCB = Range("B1000").End(xlUp).Row
For ToRow = 11 To LastRowCB
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(ToRow, "B")) Then
        '-
        MyLeft = Cells(ToRow, "A").Left
        MyTop = Cells(ToRow, "A").Top
        MyHeight = Cells(ToRow, "A").Height
        MyWidth = MyHeight = Cells(ToRow, "A").Width
        '-
        ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
         With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = "R" & ToRow
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With
    End If
Next
```

I am now trying to alter this code with little success to add the exact same kind of check box to one cell I have activated. Like I said I have the cell activated I just need to alter the code to make it do just that ActiveCell instead of the ActiveSheet. Below is the attempt I made to alter the code. I excluded the If statement because my thought is since I have the cell activated I don't need all of that.

```
ActiveCell.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
         With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = "R" & ToRow
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With
```

When I try and run this code I get a Debug on the following line.

```
ActiveCell.CheckBoxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkboxes (and other controls) are part of the worksheet, and not a cell.

While you can put a control "over" a cell, its still not part of that cell.

Just continue to use `ActiveSheet` and use ActiveCell calculate your `MyTop, MyLeft, MyHeight` and `MyWidth` values.

```
MyLeft = ActiveCell.Left
MyTop = ActiveCell.Top
MyHeight = ActiveCell.Height
MyWidth = ActiveCell.Width

ActiveSheet.Checkboxes.Add(MyLeft, MyTop, MyWidth, MyHeight).Select

With Selection
    .Caption = ""
    .Value = xlOff
    .LinkedCell = ActiveCell.Address
    .Display3DShading = False
End With
```

I've updated the code to also link the cell and stuff. Your first code example in your question does show how to do it minus the `ActiveCell.Address`!

If you want it to be `linked` explicitly to a cell in column R then you will need to make it yourself

eg: `.LinkedCell = "R" & ActiveCell.Row` otherwise `ActiveCell.Address` will link to the cell your adding the checkbox over.

Comment: Thanks Nick. This added the Check Box but it's not linking it to the cell in Column R from my With statement. How could I alter that statement to make it link to the certain row in column R like my other Check Boxes do?

Comment: You are the man Nick! This works great! I really appreciate your help!